# Warning message when using read.zoo function

Tags: r, zoo

I have data frame(df) that contains daily stock index prices covering over 4000 days. It looks like:

```
Date       Prices
1986-1-1    20
 .          .
 .          .
 .          .
 .          .
2001-08-31  40
```

I am trying to convert the data frame into zoo object using `read.zoo(df)` (read.zoo is a function in zoo package). However it gives me the following error:

```
Warning message:
In zoo(rval3, ix) :
  some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique
```

that affects the subsequent codes I apply to the object.

For a reproducibility purpose, the original data (FTSE100jensen.csv) and code (JensenPaper.R) is available on https://github.com/ahmedfsalhin/1stpaper

Comment: this means that you have duplicate dates in your data set.  Happened to me before pulling some Fed data.  You'll need to do some cleaning before converting to zoo.  One easy option is to average values for duplicate dates, then convert to zoo, but that's up to you, as long as before converting each date is unique

Comment: @DMT unfortunately it is not the case. I have just rechecked it and it has no duplicates regarding the dates.

Comment: @AhmedSalhin check `sum(duplicated(index(zoo_object)))` you should have zero otherwise....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you called `read.zoo()` without providing a value for `format=`, but your dates are formated like `"%d/%m/%Y"`, not `"%Y-%m-%d"`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why this error was occurring, but I first converted `Date` to the `Date` class and was able to call `read.zoo` without error using this:

```
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
library(zoo)
##
Data <- read.csv(
  "F:/gitData.csv",
  header=TRUE)
#
Data$Date <- as.Date(
  Data$Date,
  "%d/%m/%Y")
##
zData <- read.zoo(Data)
##
> head(zData)
             Open   High    Low  Close Volume Adj.Close
1986-01-01 1412.6 1412.6 1412.6 1412.6      0    1412.6
1986-01-02 1412.6 1420.8 1412.0 1420.5      0    1420.5
1986-01-03 1420.5 1430.0 1419.6 1429.8      0    1429.8
1986-01-06 1429.8 1436.3 1424.1 1424.1      0    1424.1
1986-01-07 1419.8 1419.8 1411.6 1415.2      0    1415.2
1986-01-08 1415.2 1419.3 1400.3 1404.2      0    1404.2
```

and everything seems to be in order, e.g. I can call `.zoo` methods properly, etc...

```
> plot(zData)
```

[image]

To address the comments above, the error message does seem to indicate that there are duplicated dates, but this is not the case:

```
> dim(Data)
[1] 4088    7
> length(unique(Data$Date))
[1] 4088
```

Comment: That works fine. Still could not find what is wrong with the original data.